# Solving environment: failed PackagesNotFoundError matplotlib=1.5.2

Tags: configuration, anaconda, arcgis

I am trying to create an Anaconda environment for use with ArcGIS 10.5.1.  I opened the Anaconda Prompt and typed:

```
C:\Users\aneme>conda create -n arc1051 python=2.7.13 numpy=1.9.3 
matplotlib=1.5.2 scipy=0.17.0 pandas pyparsing xlrd xlwt console_shortcut
```

I receive the following error:

```
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError:  The following packages are not available from 
current channels:

    - matplotlib=1.5.2

Current channels:

     - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-32
     - https://...........
     - https://.......
     etc.
```

Does anybody know what this means, and does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem is in this link:  https://github.com/conda-forge/matplotlib-feedstock.  Simply type this into the Anaconda Prompt.

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```